# How can I further improve my freezing laptop question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Commenters suggested me to address their comments in [my main post](https://superuser.com/questions/1785136/is-chrome-responsible-for-my-100-disk-usage) and I think I did. However, I have received 3 downvotes so I guess my question still isn't up to the mark. How can I further improve it?

Comment: Please let me know if I should add further information in my question

Comment: I asked several questions, and specifically indicated comments shouldn’t be used, yet every single one of my questions were answered with a comment instead of clarifying your question by editing it.  Which is the reason for my downvote.

Comment: @Ramhound I did that but after that I think I addressed your and other people's comments in my main post. Did I not?

Comment: @Ramhound Additionally, I was not exactly understanding what you were asking me to include in my main post. I even asked you to provide an example: _@Ramhound I am sorry I don't understand what additional information I should provide. Could you please give an example of what I should include in my question?_

Comment: I asked you how many tabs you had open in Chrome, and you submitted a comment that indicated you had lots, which is extremely vague and was never added to your question. I was not able to be any clearer than asking than what I actually asked. You seemingly ignored my suggestion not to submit comments to clarify your question.

Comment: @Ramhound _I asked you how many tabs you had open in Chrome,..._ Sorry at the time, I didn't realize I needed to edit my post to answer THIS SPECIFIC question as it seemed like a simple enough question to answer. Believe it or not, I was slightly confused. _You seemingly ignored my suggestion not to submit comments..._ If I wanted to do that, I would not have asked you to provide an example

Comment: @Ramhound But I understand where you are coming from. My question is answered but I still want to improve it to negate my downvotes. Do you suggest addressing everybody's comments in my post?

Answer (score 2):

While your question was still in it's infant state IMO it was a pretty poor question, and you're basically asking for an opinion:

---

[image]

---

This isn't a lot to go on, it does not show a lot of effort and your question can basically be answered by yes or no.

To improve and make it a pleasant to read question, I'd rewrite the question

- Describe / introduce the freezes and if possible circumstances in which they occur.
- Make screenshot more relevant by sorting using the disk column high > low so it shows the process with most disk access on top. It may very well be Chrome, but it is not clear from the screenshot.
- List hardware specs of the PC (CPU, hard drive capacity and type, amount of RAM.
- OS.
- Other steps already tried to solve the issue. In general people appreciate it if you describe the effort you've put into solving an issue and it also prevents people from suggesting stuff you have already tried.

Comment: Thank you for the response. _List hardware specs of the PC (CPU, hard drive capacity and type, amount of RAM. OS._ I believe I addressed these points in my main post upon the advice of other commenters. _Other steps already tried to solve the issue. In general people appreciate it if you describe the effort you've put into solving an issue and it also prevents people from suggesting stuff you have already tried._ I guess didn't answer this directly but I posted another screenshot of the Task Manager when I was running Edge and a similar freeze occurred.